# Is there a way to `next build` using less memory?

Tags: reactjs, linux, next.js

I'm serving a Next.js app from a 1gb memory server. Every time I run `next build` to redeploy my application, memory usage goes from ~70% memory to 100% and everything crawls to a halt. It typically takes 15-20 minutes to build my app as a result.

Is there a way to build my Next.js app using less memory?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `next.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

export default {
  experimental: {
    cpus: 1,
    workerThreads: false
  }
}
```

At the moment this is far from perfect, they should add an option to have a fixed number of pages generated in parallel.